# Raw packet creation causing IP fields to be incorrect order

Tags: c++, c, sockets, packet, endianness

Simply said, I am having trouble with endiness and raw packets inside the IP protocol, when I am dealing with the flags and offset fields.

I am attempting to create my own packets using UDP raw packets. I am using C style structs with **bitfields**.

I am having problems with the IP flags and Fragment Offset fields of the IP protocol. This is because of the ordering of the bytes is different. I think want to be able to use the **htons()** function to change the order of the bits, but when I do so, I believe I mess things up.

Here is a quick output of the packet I am creating. What interests us is byte 6 and byte 7. (The bold and italicized bits).

**0**       0100 0101   0001 0000   0001 1100   0000 0000   1101 0100   0011 0001   ***0000 0001   0000 1000***

**8**   0100 0000   0001 0001   0110 0111   1000 1010   0000 0001   0000 0001   0000 0001   0000 0001

**16**      0000 0011   0000 0011   0000 0011   0000 0011   0000 1000   1010 1110   0001 0001   0101 1100

**24**      0000 0000   0000 1000   0000 0000   0000 0000

I have the following structure inplace... (Take note of the bitfields for the three flags and the offset.

```
struct IPHeader
{
    unsigned char iph_ihl:4, iph_ver:4;     
    unsigned char iph_tos;                  
    unsigned short int iph_len;             
    unsigned short int iph_ident;           
    unsigned char iph_flag_X:1;                
    unsigned char iph_flag_D:1;
    unsigned char iph_flag_M:1;
    unsigned short int iph_offset:13;         
    unsigned char iph_ttl;                 
    unsigned char iph_protocol;            
    unsigned short int iph_chksum;          
    unsigned int iph_sourceip;              
    unsigned int iph_destip;                
};
```

In my code, I am attempting to set the offset to the value of 1, whilte having the D flag set. (just for example) One would think that my code then could be...

```
ipheader->iph_flag_X = 1;
ipheader->iph_flag_M = 0;
ipheader->iph_flag_D = 0;
ipheader->iph_offset = htons(1);
```

This results in the following printout for bytes 6 and 7.... ***0000 0001   0000 0001***

What I would like to see for this code is the following...   ***1000 0000   0000 0001***

The second set of byteam attempting to create my own packets using UDP raw packets. I am using C style structs with bitfields. s accuratly reflects the X flag set and the Fragment Offset to the value of 1. Keep in mind the fragment offset takes up 13 bits, and the three flags are each 1 bit.

Comment: So which is it that you get, `0000 0001 0000 1000` as described at the top or `0000 0001 0000 0001` as described below?

Answer (score 0):

Bit-fields behaviour is implemention defined.  According to K&R

```
"fields are assigned left to right on some machines and right to left on others"
```

So, your structure definition must take that into consideration.  Although you may or may not be developing on a "Little-Endian" machine, a peek at UBUNTU's IP Header definition may get you started on a more portable course (and solve your problem along the way):

```
struct ip
  {
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    unsigned int ip_hl:4;               /* header length */
    unsigned int ip_v:4;                /* version */
#endif
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    unsigned int ip_v:4;                /* version */
    unsigned int ip_hl:4;               /* header length */
#endif
    u_int8_t ip_tos;                    /* type of service */
    u_short ip_len;                     /* total length */
    u_short ip_id;                      /* identification */
    u_short ip_off;                     /* fragment offset field */
#define IP_RF 0x8000                    /* reserved fragment flag */
#define IP_DF 0x4000                    /* dont fragment flag */
#define IP_MF 0x2000                    /* more fragments flag */
#define IP_OFFMASK 0x1fff               /* mask for fragmenting bits */
    u_int8_t ip_ttl;                    /* time to live */
    u_int8_t ip_p;                      /* protocol */
    u_short ip_sum;                     /* checksum */
    struct in_addr ip_src, ip_dst;      /* source and dest address */
  };
```